# Permission Issue when persisting custom class by saving to a .txt file

Tags: c#, uwp

I am trying to save my applications viewModel class to a .txt file to allow for persisting it from one session to another.

I am following https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/serialization/walkthrough-persisting-an-object-in-visual-studio as an example.

However, I can't seem to get the permissions correct to allow my code to write to a file.

```
        private void Save()
        {
            BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();

            // Serialize the Binary Object and save to file
            using (Stream fsout = File.Create("C:\\temp\\viewModel.txt"))
            {
                bf.Serialize(fsout, dataContext);
            }
        }
```

Error Message:

```
System.UnauthorizedAccessException
  HResult=0x80070005
  Message=Access to the path 'C:\temp\viewModel.txt' is denied.
```

Above is how I am trying to create and write to the file.  I have tried running Visual Studio 2019 as administrator and that doesn't seem to help.  I have tried several other file location to no avail.  I checked that the I have permissions to the folder.  I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Can you give us some error messages from your attempts to run the code?

Comment: @LordPupazz updated with error message.

Comment: Can you manually create a file in that location using Windows Explorer?

Comment: @LordPupazz yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In UWP, access to files by path is restricted. The recommended practice is to use FileOpenPicker to select files.

But if you just save the data locally, you can use `ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder` to access the local application folder.

like this:

```cs
private async void Save()
{
    BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();

    var localFolder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
    var file = await localFolder.CreateFileAsync("viewModel.txt", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);

    // Serialize the Binary Object and save to file
    using (Stream fsout = await file.OpenStreamForWriteAsync())
    {
        bf.Serialize(fsout, dataContext);
    }
}
```

For details about saving data to local files, you can refer to this document:

- [Create and read a local file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/app-settings/store-and-retrieve-app-data#create-and-read-a-local-file)

Answer (score 0):

In that case it might be how you're creating/opening the file. Try changing your code to something like this:

```
using (Stream fsout = File.Open(@"c:\ab\testings.txt", FileMode.Create))
{
    bf.Serialize(fsout, dataContext);
}
```

Comment: That didn't work for me either. I did manage to get it to work using System.IO.Path.GetTempPath() which I have included as an answer.  Does anyone know if this is a good place to store data for the production application?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get the following to work:

```
    private void Save()
    {
        BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();

        // Serialize the Binary Object and save to file
        using (Stream fsout = new FileStream(System.IO.Path.GetTempPath() + "viewModel.txt", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.None))
        {
            bf.Serialize(fsout, dataContext);
        }
    }
```

I am however unsure if this is a good place to be storing data for the production application.